# Compile error: Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a1 = [a1]

Tags: haskell

I have a function:

```
changeIn2dList :: (Eq a) => (Int, Int) -> a -> [[a]] -> [[a]] 
changeIn2dList _ _ [] = error "Can't change empty list" 
changeIn2dList (x, y) w (z:zs) 
  | x == 0 = changeInList y w z 
  | otherwise = z:(changeIn2dList (x-1, y) w zs)
```

When I compile it, I get this error:

```
Could not deduce (a ~ [a])
 from the context (Eq a)
   bound by the type signature for
              changeIn2dList :: Eq a => (Int, Int) -> a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
   at starter/Helpers.hs:25:19-61
   `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for
          changeIn2dList :: Eq a => (Int, Int) -> a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
       at starter/Helpers.hs:25:19
 In the second argument of `changeInList', namely `w'
 In the expression: changeInList y w z
 In an equation for `changeIn2dList':
     changeIn2dList (x, y) w (z : zs)
       | x == 0 = changeInList y w z
       | otherwise = z : (changeIn2dList (x - 1, y) w zs)
```

If I remove the type definition from the function:

```
--changeIn2dList :: (Eq a) => (Int, Int) -> a -> [[a]] -> [[a]] 
changeIn2dList _ _ [] = error "Can't change empty list" 
changeIn2dList (x, y) w (z:zs) 
| x == 0 = changeInList y w z 
| otherwise = z:(changeIn2dList (x-1, y) w zs)
```

The error changes:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a1 = [a1]
In the first argument of `(:)', namely `z'
In the expression: z : (changeIn2dList (x - 1, y) w zs)
In an equation for `changeIn2dList':
    changeIn2dList (x, y) w (z : zs)
      | x == 0 = changeInList y w z
      | otherwise = z : (changeIn2dList (x - 1, y) w zs)
```

It looks like the problem is with the line

```
| otherwise = z : (changeIn2dList (x - 1, y) w zs)
```

It doesn't like the `z:([[a]])` operation. Wouldn't `z` be a list and `(changeIn2dList (x - 1, y) w zs)` be a 2D list? Why is there a problem?

---

My `changeInList` function (which works) is

```
changeInList :: (Eq a) => Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
changeInList _ _ [] = error "Can't change empty list"
changeInList x w (z:zs)
  | x == 0 = w:zs
  | otherwise = z:(changeInList (x - 1) w zs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very slight error in your code, and I think once you see it you'll realize why the compiler gave you the error it did.  In the case for `x == 0` in `changeIn2dList`, you are only calling `changeInList`, without prepending it onto the rest of the list.  If you change it to `changeInList y w z : zs`, it'll compile and work as expected.

The reason for this is because you're telling the compiler that `changeIn2dList` returns type `[[a]]`, but you return the value from `changeInList`, which is of type `[a]`, so it tries to equate `[[a]]` with `[a]`, which would have to mean that `a ~ [a]`.

When you remove the type signature, it then derives the type from the first case, and sees the problem with the second.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Also, thank you for the explanation - the error is a lot less cryptic now.

Comment: @Kevin That's great to hear.  While having your code work is always nice, understanding why it works, or why it doesn't, is more useful in the long run.